# Array Calculation PHP

Tags: php

Again I am stuck with PHP array calculation, please if anyone understands my question try to help me out, let's explain...

[data.txt content]

```
Peer             Call ID      Duration Recv: Pack  Lost       (     %) Jitter Send: Pack  Lost       (     %) Jitter
139.59.232.196   0bb9262d6a1  00:01:12 0000003558  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000001177  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0200
139.59.232.196   41283499492  00:00:00 0000000000  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000000000  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000
139.59.232.196   7033a541240  00:00:08 0000000000  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000 0000000019  0000000000 ( 0.00%) 0.0000
3 active SIP channels
```

PHP Code Starting from here.

```
$data = file_get_contents('./data.txt', TRUE);
$lines = explode("\n", $data);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!preg_match('/( 0.00%)/', $line)) {
        continue;
    }
    $data = explode(' ', $line);
    $list[] = $data;
}

foreach ($list as $qoscalc) {
    $average[] = ($qoscalc[17] * 1000 / 2);
    $jitter[] = (int)$qoscalc[14];
    $packet_loss[] = (int)$qoscalc[13];
}
print_r($average);
```

Till here the code is working fine it's giving me the output of `$average` array this >>

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 0 [2] => 0 )
```

After that, I couldn't do this math with the array, if I convert them in variable & I go with 1 data only then code is working fine, but when I try to get the result of all I couldn't make it, please help me if anyone understands my question.

```
$effective_latency = ($average + $jitter * 2 + 10 );

if ($effective_latency < 160) {
    $r_value = 93.2 - ($effective_latency / 40);
} else {
    $r_value = 93.2 - ($effective_latency - 120) / 10;
}

$r_value = $r_value - ($packet_loss * 2.5);

$mosresult = 1 + (0.035) * $r_value + (0.000007) * $r_value * ($r_value - 60) * (100 - $r_value);

$moslist[] = $mosresult;
```

I want to get all 3 array result, its suppose to be like this example: Array ( [0] => 4.40372901469 [1] => 3.40372901469 [2] => 4.90372901469 )

```
$i = 0; $t = 0; $e = 0; $g = 0; $f = 0; $p = 0; $b = 0;

foreach ($moslist as $mos) {
    $i++;
    if ($mos <= "5") {
        $qosq = 'Excellent';
        $e++;       
    } else if ($mos <= "4") {
        $qosq = 'Good';
        $g++;       
    } else if ($mos < "3") {
        $qosq = 'Fair';
        $f++;       
    } else if ($mos <= "2") {
        $qosq = 'Poor';
        $p++;       
    } else if ($mos <= "1") {
        $qosq = 'Bad';
        $b++;       
    } else {
        continue;
    }
    $t++;
}
echo $qosq, "<br><br>\n";
```

Comment: So you basically want to apply the formula that gives you $mosresult to all elements in the array? If so, the easy (although not nice from a coding point of view) would be to make that part a function and then create the resulting array by calling the function in a for loop. Using objects that tie the different values together would be a nicer, but more advanced option.

Comment: can you please help me by changing my codes?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, the simplest solution would be to create a function for calculating the mosResult

```
function getMosResult($average,$jitter,$packet_loss)
{
  $effective_latency = ($average + $jitter * 2 + 10 );

  if ($effective_latency < 160) {
      $r_value = 93.2 - ($effective_latency / 40);
  } else {
      $r_value = 93.2 - ($effective_latency - 120) / 10;
  }

  $r_value = $r_value - ($packet_loss * 2.5);

  return 1 + (0.035) * $r_value + (0.000007) * $r_value * ($r_value - 60) * (100 - $r_value);
}
```

and then applying the function in a for loop on all the results like so

```
$length = count($list);
for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++){ 
    $mosList[]=getMosResult($average[$i],$jitter[$i],$packet_loss[$i]);
}
```

This solution would not be good for a larger project as you would quickly lose consistency between the three source arrays. For a more solid solution, look into objects or t least associative arrays.